# Apex REST API call from Javascript via Ajax Toolkit

Tags: visualforce, javascript, oauth2, ajax-toolkit

I have created a GET method REST service and trying to Ajax call the service through `sforce.connection.remoteFunction` from JavaScript. Able to get the Session Id and it hitting the service. But the response was `Error 401 Unauthorized`. Is there anything I'm missing in the request?

Note: I'm Passing the session Id in the request header.

Attaching my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = setupPage;

function setupPage() {
var result = sforce.connection.login("myloginmailid", "pwd+security token"); 
sforce.connection.init(result.sessionId, 'Service URL'); 
    <!-- Salesforce Remote Connection-->  

    sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
        url : "Service URL",
        requestHeaders: {"Authorization":"Bearer"+__sfdcSessionId, "Content-Type":"application/json", "Connection":"Keep-Alive" },
        method: "GET",
        onSuccess : function(response) {
              alert("Success" +response);  
           },
       onFailure : function(response) {
              alert("Failed" + response)
          }
   });    
</script>
```

Comment: Did you setup OAuth?

Comment: @erbdex I added the domain name "https://ap1.salesforce.com/" in Remote Settings.Got the session Id through "sforce.connection.login" method.

Comment: @Dinesh can you post the script you tried ?

Comment: @responsive Attached my script. Is there anything I'm missing in request? "__sfdcSessionId" is the session id i got through these script, <script type="text/javascript">
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
 </script>

Comment: You can just set the session ID directly: `sforce.connection.sessionId = __sfdcSessionId`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got the solution,

1. In the **sforce.connection.init** method we have to pass the "**current Session Id"** of the organization from which we are requesting,
2. As **responsive** mentioned provide space between Bearer and session id.

Changed line of code:

**sforce.connection.init(__sfdcSessionId, 'Service URl');**

Answer (score 3):

First thing I am seeing is you are missing space between `Bearer` and `__sfdcSessionId`. Add space and try it

`requestHeaders: {"Authorization":"Bearer<addSpace>"+__sfdcSessionId, "Content-Type":"application/json", "Connection":"Keep-Alive" },`

Comment: I added space between Bearer and my session id , It's not working