# How to issue/send access token from apex page to connected app

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, connected-apps

We have implemented 2 OAuth flows between our app and SF where SF is auth provider - *Web Server* and *Username and Password*

Now we have use case where user is signed on SF and has to invoke our ASMX API.
Is it possible to write in SF APEX page - generate for me access token for current session and environment and to send that automatically (in message header) when I call our API ? If not what is the best approach, I would like still to keep SF as Oauth provider, do not want to provide/issue access tokens from my side in this communication.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back, I was trying to connect 2 saleforce org via Oauth/Rest API. 
I think I did something similar. 
On Salesforce org(Source) act as auth provider. I created connected app in Target org to finally get the Oauth Token.
providing small code base for that:

```
String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
// All of these u'll get once you set up connected app

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');//Note if my domain is set up use the proper domain name else use login.salesforce.com for prod or developer or test.salesforce.com for sandbox instance

    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    OAuth2 objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth2)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), OAuth2.class);
    //RequestWrapper reqst=new RequestWrapper();

    if(objAuthenticationInfo.access_token!=null) // your check for access token

    { for any further Rest API call, I was using this, which I think you needed: 
      **req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+objAuthenticationInfo.access_token);** 
      --------your further code------ }
```

Let me know in case you've any doubt over this :

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question, **Yes!**

You might not have any need to use any apex code but you can do it using javascript, and libraries that are Salesforce standard.

You can use sForce.js and/or jsForce - libraries from Salesforce

You can use the AJAX toolkit -

I cannot put the exact code for your requirement but these similar questions might give you an insight

[Fetching records by using JQuery](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127847/fetching-records-by-using-jquery)

[Apex REST API call from Javascript via Ajax Toolkit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17382/apex-rest-api-call-from-javascript-via-ajax-toolkit)